# How to check the installation of "cordova-save-image-gallery"

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova

Was my installation of "cordova-save-image-gallery" succeeded?

I got the following installation message and was tried this plugin with the following simple code including the example of github.com/agomezmoron but it did not work.

Even window.imageSaver.saveBase64Image does not do "success callback" nor "fail callback".

I am guessing there is something wrong with my installation but I don't know how to proceed my research any further.

////Installation message//////////////////////

C:\Cordova\simplecamera>npm i cordova-plugin-save-image-gallery
npm WARN com.mycompany.myteam.simplecamera@1.0.0 No repository field.

- cordova-plugin-save-image-gallery@0.0.26
  updated 1 package and audited 58 packages in 0.99s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//simple code including the example//////

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
            var base64String;

            function takePicture() {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(
                    function (imageData) { 
                        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;                
                        base64String = image.src;  
                    },
                    function (message) { console.warn('@@@Failed because: ' + message); },
                    { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, targetHeight: 100}
                );
            }          
          
            function saveToGallery() {
                //Example code on https://github.com/agomezmoron/cordova-save-image-gallery
                var params = {data: base64String, prefix: 'myPrefix_', format: 'JPG', quality: 80, mediaScanner: true};
                window.imageSaver.saveBase64Image(params,
                    function (filePath) {
                        console.log('File saved on ' + filePath);
                    },
                    function (msg) {
                        console.error('msg' + msg);
                    }
                );
                //************************************************************************** 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="takePicture();"> Take a Picture</button><br>                 
        <img id="myImage" src="none" alt=""/><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="saveToGallery();"> Save to Gallery </button>               
    </body>
</html>
```